# giving contrast effect to images using php

Tags: php, html

here is my html/php code:

```
<form method="post" action="contrast.php">
  <li><input type="image" height="200" width="200" src="show_image.php?id='2'"   
  id="image" onclick="document.getElementById('hidimgSrc').value                   
  =this.src;document.getElementById('myform').submit();" name="abc"></li> 
  </form>
```

here is the php code for contrast.php the image:

```
 <?php
    $a=(string)$_POST['abc'];
    echo $a;
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($a); 
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -80); 
    imagejpeg($image, 'contrast-sun.jpg'); 
    imagedestroy($image); 
    echo '<img src="contrast-sun.jpg" alt="Image With A Contrast Effect Applied" />'; 

   ?>
```

here the error coming is Undefined index: abc in C:\wamp\www\radha\contrast.php on line 2
that is the name of the image is not being submit properly .....so anybody plzz help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately some times image buttons won't carry the data to your php page. I've faced these problem for many times. Later i realized that

```
<input type="image" />
```

is the problem. Try with

```
<input type="submit" height="200" width="200" onclick="document.getElementById('hidimgSrc').value=this.src;document.getElementById('myform').submit();" name="abc">
```

Comment: but in this case how will i'll display the image

Comment: using type=image i m displaying image as a button from the different link

Comment: Did you tried with `<input type='submit' />` ? if it works try to style with css.

Comment: can u explain me the code u have written ... i m nt able to know how can i show image as a button using this code

Comment: Call your image as a background image for the input button using css

Comment: <form method="post" action="contrast.php">
<ul> 
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ){ ?>
<li><input type="submit" height="200" width="200" class="image" onclick="document.getElementById('hidimgSrc').value=this.src;document.getElementById('myform').submit();" name="abc" ></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul> 
</form>

Comment: ans css  is   <style type="text/css">
<!--
.image {
 backgroung-image:"show_image.php?id='<?php echo $row[0]?>'";
}
-->
</style>

Comment: Did u try this ?

`<style type="text/css">
.image { backgroung-image:"../show_image.php?id='<?php echo $row[0]?>'"; }
</style>`

Comment: Can't you load the `backround-image` as static one ?

Comment: i m nt getting ..what are u trying to say

Comment: Can u post all your html, php pages including `show_image.php`. Then i will write it for you.

Comment: thanks for your help ....but i decided to use different code as this was giving me a hell lot of trouble ..